# Decomposition of matrix exponential in python: Eigenvector matrix doesn't match

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, linear-algebra, eigenvector

When trying to reproduce the following example, where the decomposition is `T x Lambda x T^{-1}` (not named in the image but visible) where `Lambda` is a diagonal matrix of exponential eigenvalues, and `T` is some eigenvector matrix I think. I do not know how, or am unable to, calculate the matrix `T` in Python.

[image]

My code attempt is shown below. The eigenvectors `vecs` should correspond to `T`. what am I doing wrong? And is there a more appropriate function than `eigs`?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
from scipy.linalg import expm,inv

A = np.array([[5,1],[-2,2]])
eA = expm(A)
vals, vecs = eigs(A, k=2)

print(vals) #eigenvalues match Lambda in example
print(vecs) #eigenvectors don't match T in example
print(inv(vecs))
```

Returns:

```
[4.+0.j 3.+0.j]

[[ 0.70710678 -0.4472136 ]
 [-0.70710678  0.89442719]]

[[2.82842712 1.41421356]
 [2.23606798 2.23606798]]
```

when they should be matrices of positive/negative 1's and 2's as shown in the image.

Comment: The columns of `T` (and of `vecs`) are the eigenvectors.  Eigenvectors are not unique. Any nonzero multiple of an eigenvector associated with an eigenvalue is also an eigenvector associated with that eigenvalue.   If you compare each column of `vecs` with the corresponding column of `T`, you'll see that the only difference is a multiplicative factor.  So the calculation looks OK.

Comment: but I do not see the matrix `T`, as shown in the image, anywhere in the python output. am i supposed to adjust them for the multiplicative factor you speak of

Comment: @develarist Your `vecs` is `T`. Try multiply `vecs` with `vals` as diagonal and then `inv(vecs)` you will see you get back `A`.

Comment: you're right that `vecs @ np.diag(vals) @ inv(vecs) = A`, but I still don't see how `vecs = T`

Comment: @develarist I'm not saying `vecs=T`. The first column of `vecs` is the first column of `T` scaled. The same goes to the other column. See the first comment that eigenvectors are not unique (and it should be trivial to see if you understand what eigenvector is)..

Comment: ok I will have to read more on them being non-unique. i was going by "Your `vecs` is `T`" that's all

Comment: @develarist You can look at it this way. Suppose you know that A x = lambda x. What can you say about a x, where a is a scalar factor? What is A (a x) equal to? Hope this helps.